# How to transfer potato chips from a bag into a solid container

Tags: cleaning, food, snack-food

A way I use to prevent any part of my hands from getting dirty from eating chips is to transfer a bag of chips from the original bag to a long Pringle cylindrical container, then just hold the container and gradually bite off the chips either in 1 full bite if they are small enough or in 2 bites, returning the other uneaten half into the container.

I would usually just cut a small hole from the bag of chips from one of the corner such that it fits the size of the biggest chip I would expect. However due to the clustered nature of chips, my estimation is often bad and hence I have to adjust the hole, and the entire trial and error process of transferring either ends up in a quick mess of some chips missing the opening or takes quite abit of time for a simple task.

> Does anyone know of a better way to transfer the chips from a bag to a container? Any other alternative ways of storage can also be suggested if it solves my problem under my situation.

Answers to queries that may arise:

I chose to eat chips using a container as the other ways that I know of from [here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/how-to-eat-chips-with-out-getting-hands-dirty/1776#1776) don't seem very convenient as I'm always on my computer typing and don't really want to use another utensil of some sort. My current approach was somewhat inspired from an unaccepted answer from the same page, but wanted a way to keep the chips fresher as the chips are supposed to last me 24 hours rather than a few hours, exposing it to too much air will reduce its crispy texture.

I chose to eat chips from bags instead of the ones that are already available in containers since the brand I like, just happens to be available in my country only in the form of bags, and bags are generally cheaper in terms of net weight per cent.

Answer (score 1):

Take a short break from your work.
Wash your hands and dry them well.

Open your chips bag and use your hands to stack the chips in your chosen container.
Wash your hands and go back to work.

Doing it this way is faster, so the time you spend washing your hands before and after the job comes out of the time you usually used to fiddle with the bag.